# IOS automatically zooms in when i set font size below 16px on iPhone

Tags: html, css, reactjs, iphone, next.js

I am testing my app on iPhone which is working fine on iPad but on iPhone when I click on a text field the view automatically zooms in. if I set the font size 16px or larger then everything will be working fine. there is an issue what if we have a requirement in which font size is below 16px.

My code:

```
<Form.Control
 id="search-event"
 value={query}
 color="normal"
 required
 type="text"
 placeholder={MODAL_SEARCH_BAR.PLACEHOLDER}
 onChange={handleInput}
 ref={inputRef}
 className="bg-transparent"
 />
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps ...? Use with caution, this is quite hacky ...

```
// prevent safari zooming in inputs
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) {

  input {
    font-size: [your fontsize];
  }
}
```